# Updating an array of ID's

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm trying to update an array of id's instead of just one id but with no succes. I'm not even sure on how the payload data should look like.

This is my current request  payload:

```
query: "mutation { 
     addStudentToGroup(
              id: " [5c3b9884277bbd61dcdc174b,5c3b9884277bbd61dcdc174c]", 
              groupId: "5c3b974157905b2808373e3c"
     ) 
     { id } 
} "
```

And in my GraphQL I did this:

```
    addStudentToGroup: {
        type: StudentType,
        args: {
            id: {type: GraphQLList(GraphQLID)},
            groupId: {type: GraphQLID}
        },
        resolve(parent, args) {
            return Student.updateMany(
                { id: { $in: args.id} },
                { $set: { groupId: args.groupId }}
                );
        }
    },
```

But what it returns to me is:

```
{"data":{"addStudentToGroup":{"id":null}}}
```

Why is this not working? It does work when I use `findByIdAndUpdate`

Comment: Put the quotes inside the braces: `id: ["5c3b9884277bbd61dcdc174b", "5c3b9884277bbd61dcdc174c"]`. GraphQL accepts your whole string as a single string.

Comment: Same thing with this as payload request: `query: "mutation { addStudentToGroup(id: ["5c3b9884277bbd61dcdc174a"], groupId: "5c3b974157905b2808373e3c") { id } }`

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `GraphQLList` but I believe you have to define your id argument as `id: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLID) }` (notice the `new` keyword), i.e. GraphQLList is not a type per se, but a constructor.